# NativeScript Vue: FormattedString and Label truncates the string on IPHONE

Tags: ios, vue.js, mobile, nativescript

I am new to NativeScript but I have some background in web development:
I have an issue which I don't understand its reasoning, and it is reproducible only
on **iphone** (android works fine), here is a sample of the code:

```
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column">
        <Label @tap="outsideKeyboardTap">
          <FormattedString>
            <Span
              :text="$t('sometext')"
            <Span
              :key="someKey"
              :text="func(this.someNumber)"
          </FormattedString>
        </Label>
        <Label @tap="outsideKeyboardTap">
          <FormattedString>
            <Span
              :text="$t('sometext')"
            <Span
              :key="someKey2"
              :text="func(this.someNumber)"
          </FormattedString>
        </Label>
      </FlexboxLayout>
```

So the issue on Iphone is that the text in both Labels ended up being truncated (string is cut and 3 dots added in the end of the string)
there is no CSS related to overflow nor any code that defines the Label length.
and again, **android** is working as expcted.
**can any one shed some light on why **iphone** might add truncation to the final output?**

I ended up using this code which works fine (**BUT i want to understand why the above didn"t**)

```
<StackLayout class="limit-text-container" @tap="outsideKeyboardTap">
        <FlexboxLayout>
          <Label :text="$t('sometext')"/>
          <Label :key="someKey1" :text="$t('sometext')"/>            
        </FlexboxLayout>
        <FlexboxLayout>
          <Label :text="$t('sometext')"/>
          <Label :key="someKey2" :text="getFormattedLimit"/>            
        </FlexboxLayout>
      </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of how ios displays Label, it is normal.

What I mean is when you display a Label (without a specific width) with a variable text. the ios device will set the width of the Label to the width of the first value of text. So if you update the value later to a larger text, the label will not update its width, thus the truncate.

what you need to do is explicitly set the width of Labels and FormattedString to 100% of the container or whatever you want it to be.

Another interesting property is textWrap, the default value is 'false' which is why you have the ..., if you want it to go to the line set textWrap to true.

Hope thats what you've been asking, and that Ive been clear enough.

Comment: thanks! I will try to set the width to 100% and see if it works.
regardless, I am wondering how could I have figured it out without any ios native knowledge, since the same code behaves differently in android.